# Instrumental Variables and orthogonality conditions

Tags: statistics

To obtain the method of moment estimate for instrument variables,
we use the moment condition $z'\varepsilon=0$ in the exact identified
case (number of endogenous variables = number of instruments) or $\hat{x}'\varepsilon=0$
in the overidentified case where the hat represents ttted value of
the endogenous variable in a first stage regression on the instrumets.
We use the sample counterpart and replace the true errors by the residuals.
In the former case, we obtain $\hat{\beta}_{IV}=(z'x)^{-1}(z'y)$
and in the latter $\hat{\beta}_{2\mathrm{SLS}}=(\hat{x}'\hat{x})^{-1}(\hat{x}'y)$.
The intuition for the usual Sargan test of overidentifying restrictions
is that we regress the endogenous variable on the instruments in the
first stage, obtain the predicted value of the endogenous variables,
use these predicted values in the second stage on the RHS and obtain
the (possibly) unbiased and conistent estimate of our parameters.
We then use this estimate of the paramaters to obtain unbiased estimates
of the true errors (the residuals in the second stage) and run the
following regression: $e=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 z_1+\cdots+\alpha_k z_k+u_k$
where $e$ represent the residuals (unbiased estimates of the true
errors) and $z$ represent the various instruments.

We then run a usual $NR^2$ test to test the joint significance
of the instruments. If instruments are valid, then we should not be
able to reject the null of orthogonality. My question is that shouldnt
this always be the case by construction? After all, we use this specific
moment condition in the first place! Any help is much appreciated.